# Проверка состоит ли пользователь в канале

Tags: python, telebot

Задача сделать так , чтобы бот проверял состоит ли человек в канале. Попытался получить `user_id` и проверить его статус в указанном канале.

```
import telebot
import config

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    statuss = ['creator', 'administrator', 'member']
    for chri in statuss:
        if chri == bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='@pomogaikachannel', user_id=message.from_user.id).status:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Начнем!')
            break
    
        text_handler(message)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Подпишитесь на канал @pomogaikachannel ') 

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

После запуска кода в консоле отображается `(__init__.py:455 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body: [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: user not found"}']"` хотя пользователь существует и находится в канале. В чём может быть проблема? И как с ней разобраться?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `chat_id='@pomogaikachannel'` указать на прямую `chat_id=-1001457215242` либо `chat_id=message.chat.id`

Comment: @5c0rp, спасибо за комментарий , но всё же не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Попробуйте таким образом:

statuss = ['creator', 'administrator', 'member']
user_status = str(bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id).status)    
if user_status in statuss:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Начнем!')
    text_handler(message)
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Подпишитесь на канал @pomogaikachannel ')
```

Comment: Генерируется та же ошибка - user not found

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в том , что бота нужно было добавить в администраторы канала и предоставить ему нужные права. Также строчка `text_handler(message)` оказалась лишней и её нужно просто убрать.